# Unable to obtain configuration from discovery endpoint on IIS when hostnames are used

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, jwt, bearer-token, openiddict

I have a Javascript SPA that uses access tokens to talk to a backend API / Auth server. I'm using OpenIddict and JWT Bearer authentication on our combined API / Authorization server.  We are using the Implicit flow.

For the time being, I am not using SSL - all requests are just http.

Everything has been configured and works correctly on my dev machine.  When I publish these 2 sites to IIS everything still works fine when using an IP addresses for the 2 websites that are set up (there is 1 website for the Javascript SPA, and 1 website for the API / Auth server).

So basically I have 2 websites at the same IP address running on 2 different ports:

`1) SPA     192.168.1.50:3000`

`2) AuthServer  192.168.1.50:5959`

Now I want to enable hostnames for these sites.  I now have edited the IIS bindings in order to bind these 2 sites to a host name like so:

`1) SPA  app.mycompany:3000`

`2) AuthServer app.mycompany:5959`

When I do this, I am getting a message about not being able to access the .well-known/openid-configuration endpoint and am getting a JWT Bearer exception when trying to hit the UserInfo endpoint.

I can hit my SPA, get redirected to the Auth Server's login page and then successfully login.  By looking at the web requests in Fiddler I see that I can hit the authorize end point and now have an access_token.  As soon as the discovery step happens though things break.
The discovery end point can't be found and then immediately after that the userinfo endpoint is prevented from being hit because the bearer authentication fails.

By examining my logs I can see that JWT Bearer token fails to validate on the the UserInfo endpoint.

When this discovery endpoint is requested:
`app.mycompany:5959/.well-known/openid-configuration`

This is the error message I am getting:
   `IDX10803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'http://app.mycompany.com:5959/.well-known/openid-configuration`

And in my logs this is what I'm seeing at the point where the UserInfo controller is requested:

`2017-11-09 14:12:35.7510|1|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost|Request starting HTTP/1.1 OPTIONS http://app.mycompany:5959/connect/userinfo

2017-11-09 14:12:35.7510|1|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware|OPTIONS requests are not supported 
2017-11-09 14:12:35.7510|1|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService|The request is a preflight request. 
2017-11-09 14:12:35.7510|2|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService|The request has an origin header: 'http://app.mycompany:3000'. 
2017-11-09 14:12:35.7510|4|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService|Policy execution successful. 
2017-11-09 14:12:35.7510|9|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel|Connection id "0HL97NQJHQ576" completed keep alive response. 
2017-11-09 14:12:35.7510|2|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost|Request finished in 6.2953ms 204

2017-11-09 14:12:35.7510|1|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost|Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://app.mycompany:5959/connect/userinfo

2017-11-09 14:12:35.7510|4|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware|The request path /connect/userinfo does not match a supported file type 
2017-11-09 14:12:35.7510|2|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService|The request has an origin header: 'http://app.mycompany:3000'. 
2017-11-09 14:12:35.7510|4|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService|Policy execution successful. 
2017-11-09 14:12:35.7510|0|DEBUG|OpenIddict.OpenIddictHandler|The default userinfo request handling was skipped from user code. 
2017-11-09 14:12:35.7664|9|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler|AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was not authenticated. 
2017-11-09 14:12:35.7664|1|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Tree.TreeRouter|Request successfully matched the route with name '(null)' and template 'connect/userinfo'. 
2017-11-09 14:12:35.7664|1|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker|Executing action ApiAuthServer.Controllers.UserinfoController.Userinfo (ApiAuthServer) 
2017-11-09 14:12:35.7664|2|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService|The request has an origin header: 'http://app.mycompany:3000'. 
2017-11-09 14:12:35.7664|4|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService|Policy execution successful. 
2017-11-09`

**14:12:35.7664|3|ERROR|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler|Exception occurred while processing message. IDX10803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'http://app.mycompany:5959/.well-known/openid-configuration'.**

If I navigate directly to `app.mycompany:5959/.well-known/openid-configuration` from outside the server in a browser, I can hit that discovery endpoint and see the json data.  It works.

But if I try to access that endpoint from within the IIS server I get the same error message.  I can't seem to access that on the IIS box.  But if I remove the host name binding and go back to IP addresses, I can successfully hit the discovery endpoint even on the IIS box and the app works fine.

So I am really at a loss of what the problem is.  Not sure if there is some IIS setting I need to tweak, or if this is a bug in the JWT Bearer middleware or if it is something to do with OpenIddict.

I just want to be able to use hostnames on IIS for my app(s)

Comment: May be this will help ? https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation/issues/55

Comment: Thanks Muqeet - I had already seen that link and tried the suggestions there.  I am not using SSL so the certificate fix doesn't apply.  I also tried running the apps under the Administrator role on IIS and still had the same issue.